# Remove permanent redirect in wamp

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I used the following code in wamp http.conf of apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >

   ServerName abc.com
   Redirect permanent / http://www.xyz.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

But now i cannot access abc .com  after removing the the code from the file . I guess because of Redirect Permanent . Help me to remove the permanent redirect from wamp .

Comment: You've removed the code and it is still redirecting? Did you restart Apache?

Comment: If you use firefox, you can try the following: Open history, search for 'abc.com', rightclick ->[forget website] (NOT delete). This fixed some redirect .htaccess problems for me, it might work here.

Comment: oGeez yes i did but it did not work 

@Mattijin Thanks man you are saver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser caches the 301 Moved Permanently, until told otherwise. It is default behavior :

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2

I think a ctrl-F5 and/or a cache cleaning is enough.